# Merchant SDK PHP

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, api-gateway

I am using the following payment gateway integration from paypal

https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-php

1. Authorisation of creditcard works fine , the response object gives me the authorisation ID

   DoDirectPaymentResponseType Object ( [Amount] =>  
    [AVSCode] => A 
   [CVV2Code] => M 
   [TransactionID] => 77590473BS040440N
    [TransactionPendingReason] => 
   [PendingReason] => 
   [PaymentStatus] => 
   [FMFDetails] => 
   [ThreeDSecureResponse] =>
    [PaymentAdviceCode] =>
    [Timestamp] => 2024-01-18T07:29:14Z [Ack] => Success 
   [CorrelationID] => 8db154f55cecc 
   [Errors] => 
   [Version] => 204.0 
   [Build] => 56068150 )
2. Capture of the Authorisation works fine, I pass the authorisation ID to capture the payment.

Problem: I dont know why I dont get the payment ID (or transaction ID) of the completed transaction.

See below the response text

```
(
    [PaymentTransactionDetails] => 
    [ThreeDSecureDetails] =>
    [Timestamp] => 2024-01-18T03:35:43Z
    [Ack] => Success
    [CorrelationID] => 8e94f669b1481
    [Errors] => 
    [Version] => 204.0
    [Build] => 57991821
)

DoCaptureResponseType Object
( 
[DoCaptureResponseDetails] =>
[Timestamp] => 2024-01-18T03:40:13Z
[Ack] => Failure 
[CorrelationID] => 37f66a0e63bdf
[Errors] => 
[Version] => 204.0
[Build] => 58313039 )
```

**The completed Transaction cannot be refunded or reversed because I donot have transaction ID!** 
Can someone help please?

Comment: Edit your question to always include both the entire request and the entire response of each step. Your question shows a failed capture. Anyway, this is an extremely old integration (more than 15 years) that you should not be using for anything new. See the current guide, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/advanced/integrate